# How do I do a math filter in Django database request?

Tags: python, django, database, filter, models

I've got a model which has the following columns in database: "corrects" and "incorrects".

I want to do a filter that takes only the > 80%.

F.e: (corrects * 100 / (corrects + incorrects)) > 80

How do I do this?

Comment: post your model and your best attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `F` ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)) expressions to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), then filter on the annotation:

```
from django.db.models import F

YourModel.objects.annotate(ratio=100*F('corrects')/(F('corrects')+F('incorrects')))
                 .filter(ratio__gt=80)
```